# Replace ImageIcon with JButton pressed

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, action, imageicon

I am having trouble replacing ImageIcon with a first ImageIcon whereupon a Jbutton is pressed. So far I have tried replacing the frame, .setIcon(myNewImage);, and .remove();. Not sure what to do now... (I'll need to replace and resize them.) Here is my code. (It is supposed to be like one of those Japanese dating games... please ignore that the pictures are local I have no site to host them yet.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.Box;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import java.util.Scanner;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;  

public class NestedPanels extends JPanel {

        JPanel southBtnPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(3, 2, 1, 1)); //grid layout of buttons and declaration of panel SoutbtnPanel
        JButton b = new JButton("Say Hello");//1
        JButton c = new JButton("Say You Look Good");//1
        JButton d = new JButton("Say Sorry I'm Late");//1
        JButton e2 = new JButton("So where are we headed?");//2
        JButton f = new JButton("Can we go to your place?");//2
        JButton g = new JButton("I don't have any money for our date...");//2

   public NestedPanels() { //implemeted class

            //add action listener
            b.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    button1Clicked(e);//when button clicked, invoke method
                }
            });
            c.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    button2Clicked(e);//when button clicked, invoke method
                }
            });
           d.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    button3Clicked(e);//when button clicked, invoke method
                }
            }); 

            e2.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    button4Clicked(e);//when button clicked, invoke method
                }
            });

            f.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    button5Clicked(e);//when button clicked, invoke method
                }
            });

            g.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    button6Clicked(e);//when button clicked, invoke method
                }
            });

      southBtnPanel.add(b);
      southBtnPanel.add(c);
      southBtnPanel.add(d);

      setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(1, 1, 1, 1)); //layout of buttons "Button text"
      setLayout(new BorderLayout());
      add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension(600, 600))); //space size of text box webapp over all
      add(southBtnPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

}
   private static void createAndShowGui() {//class to show gui
        NestedPanels mainPanel = new NestedPanels(); //mainPanel new class of buttons instantiation
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Date Sim 1.0");//title of webapp on top
        frame.getContentPane().add(mainPanel);
        ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon("C:/Users/wchri/Pictures/10346538_10203007241845278_2763831867139494749_n.jpg");
        JLabel label = new JLabel(icon);
        mainPanel.add(label);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.HIDE_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private void button1Clicked(ActionEvent e) {
        southBtnPanel.removeAll();
        southBtnPanel.add(e2);
        southBtnPanel.add(f);
        southBtnPanel.add(g);
        southBtnPanel.revalidate();
        southBtnPanel.repaint();
        String msg = ((JButton)e.getSource()).getActionCommand() ;
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Hey there! Ready to get started?", "Christian feels good!", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE); //display button Action
    }

    private void button2Clicked(ActionEvent e) {

        southBtnPanel.removeAll();
        southBtnPanel.add(e2);
        southBtnPanel.add(f);
        southBtnPanel.add(g);
        southBtnPanel.revalidate();
        southBtnPanel.repaint();
        String msg = ((JButton)e.getSource()).getActionCommand() ;
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Ugh... thanks! You too ready?!", "Christian is a bit... Embarrased.", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE); //display button Action
    }

    private void button3Clicked(ActionEvent e) {

        southBtnPanel.removeAll();
        southBtnPanel.add(e2);
        southBtnPanel.add(f);
        southBtnPanel.add(g);
        southBtnPanel.revalidate();
        southBtnPanel.repaint();
        String msg = ((JButton)e.getSource()).getActionCommand() ;
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "It's ok! Just make sure it doesn't happen again!", "Christian is a bit angry!", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE); //display button Action
    }

    private void button4Clicked(ActionEvent e) {
        NestedPanels mainPanel = new NestedPanels(); //mainPanel new class of buttons instantiation
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Date Sim 1.0");//title of webapp on top
        frame.getContentPane().add(mainPanel);
        JLabel label = new JLabel();
        ImageIcon imageTwo = new ImageIcon("C:/Users/wchri/Documents/chrisferry.jpg");
        mainPanel.add(label);
        label.setIcon(imageTwo);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.HIDE_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.getContentPane().add(mainPanel);
          String msg = ((JButton)e.getSource()).getActionCommand() ;
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Let's take the ferry to NYC!", "Christian feels good!", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE); //display button Action

    }

    private void button5Clicked(ActionEvent e) {
        NestedPanels mainPanel = new NestedPanels(); //mainPanel new class of buttons instantiation
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Date Sim 1.0");//title of webapp on top
        frame.getContentPane().add(mainPanel);
        JLabel label = new JLabel();
        ImageIcon imageThree = new ImageIcon("C:/Users/wchri/Pictures/Screenshots/chrisart.jpg");
        mainPanel.add(label);
        label.setIcon(imageThree);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.HIDE_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.getContentPane().add(mainPanel);
        String msg = ((JButton)e.getSource()).getActionCommand() ;
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Don't you think it's a bit soon for that?", "Christian is embarrassed...", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE); //display button Action

    }

    private void button6Clicked(ActionEvent e) {
        NestedPanels mainPanel = new NestedPanels(); //mainPanel new class of buttons instantiation
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Date Sim 1.0");//title of webapp on top
        frame.getContentPane().add(mainPanel);
        JLabel label = new JLabel();
        ImageIcon imageFour = new ImageIcon("C:/Users/wchri/Downloads/chrismoney.jpg");
        mainPanel.add(label);
        label.setIcon(imageFour);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.HIDE_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.getContentPane().add(mainPanel);
        String msg = ((JButton)e.getSource()).getActionCommand() ;
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "I got money!", "Christian is ballin'", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE); //display button Action
        }

   public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println("Welcome to Date Sim 1.0 with we1. Are you ready to play? Yes/No?");

        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        String confirm = in.nextLine();

        if (confirm.equalsIgnoreCase("Yes")) {
            System.out.println("Ok hot stuff... Let's start.");

            NestedPanels mainPanel = new NestedPanels();

        } else {

            System.out.println("Maybe some other time!"); 
            return;
        }

         SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
         @Override
         public void run() {
            createAndShowGui();
         }
      });
   }
}
```

Comment: What button? What image?

Answer (score 2):

Here is [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates changing an icon on a `JButton` when it is clicked:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingConstants;

public class ChangeButtonIcon extends JPanel{

    private URL[] urls = {
      new URL("https://findicons.com/files/icons/345/summer/128/cake.png"),
      new URL("http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/atyourservice/service-categories/128/Sweets-icon.png"),
      new URL("https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcS_FkBgG3_ux0kCbfG8mcRHvdk1dYbZYsm2SFMS01YvA6B_zfH_kg"),
      };

    private int iconNumber = 0;
    private JButton button;

    public ChangeButtonIcon() throws IOException {

        button = new JButton();
        button.setIcon(new ImageIcon(urls[iconNumber]));
        button.setHorizontalTextPosition(SwingConstants.CENTER);
        button.addActionListener(e -> swapIcon());
        add(button);
    }

    private void swapIcon() {

        iconNumber = iconNumber >= (urls.length -1) ? 0 : iconNumber+1;
        button.setIcon(new ImageIcon(urls[iconNumber]));
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{
        JFrame window = new JFrame();
        window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        window.add(new ChangeButtonIcon());
        window.pack();
        window.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

I find writting MCVE a very useful technique. Not only it makes helping much easier, it 
is a powerful debugging tool. It many case, while preparing one, you are likely to find the problem. 
It should represent the problem or the question asked. **Not** your application.

Comment: Thanks. I'll fix it.